# integrating sonarqube with jenkins insufficient privileges error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jh7utASgKj4 to integrate sonarqube with jenkins. However, I get the insufficient privileges error when scanning the code by sonarqube server. The version of sonarqube server is 6.7. how can I solve this problem?

Here is the analysis properties in the jenkins project

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey = test-sonar

# Path to source directory
sonar.sources = /var/jenkins_home/workspace/$JOB_NAME/test-sonar/src

# bind sonar.java.binaries property
sonar.java.binaries=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/$JOB_NAME/test-sonar/target/classes
```

Here is the output of console.

```
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
INFO: 16 files to be analyzed
INFO: 16/16 files analyzed
INFO: 5 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 8 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 132ms, dir size=124 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 48ms, zip size=61 KB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 48.028s
INFO: Final Memory: 15M/304M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Insufficient privileges
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the Sonar Analysis via Execute shell plugin for Jenkins, you need to supply the Username Password of a User which has the Execute Analysis rights on the SonarQube server you are trying to access.

To supply the username in the shell, you can use

`-Dsonar.login=yourLoginName -Dsonar.password=*****`

To set the Execute Analysis permission you can ask your DevOps team to give you access or if you are looking into that,

```
Goto Administration > Security > User/Groups.
```

Comment: thank you for Vighnesh Pai and Garima. It is because of the Execute Analysis permission and Create Project is not open that causes this error. Once the login user gets these two permissions, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you configure the Sonarqube UserID and Password having privileges to access sonar server (execute analysis permissions) in the Sonar plugin for Jenkins. This error might appear for 5.3 and higher versions when the anonymous access to sonar is disabled.